# Adding Roles to MobileServices in Azure (ACS)

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, azure, role-base-authorization

I am trying to learn about how to do Roles in ACS. I have a Windows Store *App* (*not* a website :-), and I need *Administrator* and a *Member* roles - but finding even very basic documentation or tutorials for something like this is proving very difficult for me.

All I have found are a bunch of references to ASP.NET or Azure Websites stuff - which I can't use, since a Store app is not a Website - and doesn't use ASP.NET.

I have Azure Mobile Services for my Windows Store app. Is there any information that you know of that could be of help?

I'm surprised that Roles don't seem to be covered in the samples/reference/tutorials section anywhere on the Azure website (unless I've missed it - several times).

Take, for example, this scenario. Here, in the Script tab of the Management Portal, I insert some text into the table associated with the currently logged in user (via the `insert` function):

```
var SendGrid = require('sendgrid').SendGrid;

function insert(item, user, request) {
        item.userId = user.userId;
        request.execute(
            {
                success: function() {
                    request.respond();

                    // Send email in the background.
                    sendEmail(item);
                }
            }
        );
}
```

The above code inserts some text into the table and then sends an email to that user. But, how could I adapt this code, so that it would (pseudo code):

```
if item.text == "administrator"
   then insert userid into admin column
else
   then insert userid into member column
```

Any help at all will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A role is simply a claim, and ACS is all about claims, but if you're using Mobile Services, you're not (AFAIK) going through ACS so you don't have the opportunity to translate say a UserID claim into a Role claim. What identity provider are you using for Azure Mobile Services? and are you maintaining the roles/assignments or expecting that to be part of the directory you're using for auth?

Comment: @JimO'Neil I am using Microsoft Account (Formally known as Live ID) as my ID Provider. I don't mind having to maintain these roles myself, so long as it's not a manual process (can be done within code).

Comment: well you can add a roles table to your WAMS database (you can attach to it with any SQL Server client tool) and then within your scripts you can use the mssql object to add a join to your roles table on the user.userID that comes in to get their role(s).  This means though that you'll need to populate roles based on the opaque userID you get from Live or build in a registration process for your app to set up that table - sort of depends on who controls the sign-ups: "you" or is it self-serve.

Comment: @JimO'Neil Thanks, what I was thinking was what I think you just said: When the user signs in with their Microsoft Account, add them to a Role and associate that role, and any other profile info I gather from them, with the userId provided by ACS? I was going to do it this way without asking a question, but I keep thinking there must be a more... proper way (if you know what I mean). But I'm fine with this.

Comment: well, if the roles were something part of AD then you wouldn't want to recreate, but sounds like you'll have to maintain them "somewhere" anyway

Comment: @Aeron, I am trying to create a similar service where I have users with roles. How did you go about implementing this - especially for users that sign in using microsoft or fb accounts

Answer (score 1):

It is not really an answer, but it is also too long for a comment, and I think it is really important.

First of all, when using authentication from the [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/mobile-services/), you are **not using** [Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/identity/). So, there is no Active Directory, there are no (additional) claims when one uses Mobile Services. This must be very clear, because I see continuous misunderstanding and confusion. @Joey still asks for, and refers ACS as federation provider for his application, which **is not** the case if he relies on the Mobile Services authentication mechanism.

So, the roles assignment must totally be handled by your application logic with additional table as Jim describes.

However roles assignment in general is interesting topic, and really is not part of any tutorial or documentation. And it is not part of such, because Role Assignment is part of business logic of the application itself, not part of the Authentication service. There is very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375253/setting-up-azure-acs-roles), which however again does not answer in detail how to assign roles. The foundation and main issue to solve is: `How to assign administrator role`. Everything else, can be solved by adding appropriate UI for the application administrators. Still, this question is not subject to a short SO answer.